# QObject and QThread relations

Tags: pyqt4, qthread, qobject

I have a pyqt4 gui which allows me to import multiple .csv files. I've created a loop that goes through this list of tuples that have the following parameters `(filename + location of file, filename, bool,bool, set of dates in file)=tup`. 
I've created several classes that my gui frequently refers to in order to pull parameters off a projects profile. Let's call this class `profile()`. I also have another class that has a lot of functions based on formatting, such as datetime, text edits,etc...let's call this class`MyFormatting()`. Then I created a `QThread` class that is created for each file in the list, and this one is called `Import_File(QThread)`. And lets say this class takes in a few parameters for the `__init__(self,tup)`.

My ideal goal is to be able to make an independent instance of `MyFormatting()` and `profile()` for the `Import_File(QThread)`. I am trying to get my head around on how to utilize the QObject capabilities to solve this..but I keep getting the error that the thread is being destroyed while still running.

```
for tup in importedlist:
    importfile = Import_File(tup)
    self.connect(importfile,QtCore.SIGNAL('savedfile(PyQt_PyObject()'),self.printstuffpassed)
    importfile.start()
```

I was thinking of having the two classes be declared as

```
MyFormatting(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)

    def func1(self,stuff):
         dostuff
    def func2(self):
         morestuff

profile(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)

    def func11(self,stuff):
         dostuff
    def func22(self):
         morestuff
```

AND for the QThread:

```
Import_File(QThread):
    def __init__(self,tup):
        QThread.__init(self)
        common_calc_stuff = self.calc(tup[4])
        f = open(tup[0] + '.csv', 'w')
        self.tup = tup
        # this is where I thought of pulling an instance just for this thread
        self.MF = MyFormatting()
        self.MF_thread = QtCore.QThread()
        self.MF.moveToThread(self.MF_thread)
        self.MF_thread.start()

        self.prof = profile()
        self.prof_thread = QtCore.QThread()
        self.prof.moveToThread(self.prof_thread)
        self.prof_thread.start()


    def func33(self,stuff):
         dostuff
         self.prof.func11(tup[4])

    def func44(self):
         morestuff

    def run(self):
        if self.tup[3] == True:
            self.func33
            self.MF.func2
        elif self.tup[3] ==False:
            self.func44
        if self.tup[2] == True:
            self.prof.func22
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('savedfile()',)
```

Am I totally thinking of it the wrong way? How can I keep to somewhat of the same structure that I have for the coding and still be able to implement the multithreading and not have the same resource tapped at the same time, which I think is the reason why my qui keeps crashing? Or how can I make sure that each instance of those objects get turned off that they don't interfere with the other instances?

Comment: You've got a few problems with your code. 1) You aren't holding a reference to the QThread, so that's why you get the object destroyed message (each iteration of the loop overwrites the variable holding the reference to the QThread. 2) You are using the old style of signals/slots which may give you grief in the future (see [here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html)). 3) Your GUI is likely crashing because you are (probably) accessing it from outside the main thread. This is forbidden! You need to emit a signal back to the main thread and update the GUI there.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/pyqt/2775/using-threads-with-pyqt#t=20161111002348120811 for a basic example (and some guidelines on thread safety)

Comment: I tried creating a dummy trial with the example in your second comment but I keep getting 'native Qt signal is not callable'

Comment: Sorry, there is a bug in that example (I've fixed it but it is awaiting approval now so you may not be able to see it). The line `thread.started(...)` should actually read `thread.started.connect(...)`. `started` is a signal with a method `connect`, not a callable! Hope that fixes the issue.

Comment: Thanks for that...Im still trying to get my head around how to implement it..Im an example kind of guy.